# Janrain Google+ sign-in invalid client

Tags: janrain

I am trying to sign-in using the google+ provider in Janrain but I am getting the error:

```
The OAuth client was deleted.
```

The page to manage the providers in Janrain just sends me to a blank page in the developer dashboard. Has Janrain changed something in their policy or doing maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

Stagleton, Do you also have Google as a provider? I know that Google has deprecated Google, and want users to switch over to Google+. What is your Janrain app name, so I can take a look?